# CakePhp 3. query combine where IN LIKE

Tags: sql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

My table looks like:

```
 id  | tags
 ---------------------------------
 974 | Hip-Hop;Rap
 984 | Hip-Hop;Underground Hip-Hop
```

And i want query diffrent Tags and get the id's. For example

```
$searchTags=['Rap','Unterground Hip-Hop'];

$table = TableRegistry::get('MyTable')->find();

$songIds = $table->select(['id'])
                 ->where(['tags IN LIKE' => $searchTags]);
```

Is there a possibility to combine IN and LIKE oder another solution?

Comment: When it comes to SQL stuff, please always mention the DBMS that you are using (ie MySQL, Postgres, etc...). Side note: If possible you should get your schema fixed instead, and use a proper many-to-many association for your tags. Searching/Querying such string sets is usually highly inefficient.

Comment: sry... im using a MySql db...

Comment: I would also advise you to fix your schema. Ideally, tags should be on a new table.

Comment: If you really can't fix the schema, you could use a subquery to first find the tag ids that will be used in the `where` clause. But fixing the schema would be far better for the future indeed.